# UWP - horizontally scrollable view inside grid view

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm creating a sort of bookkeeper and would like to make each section horizontally scrollable (kinda like ibooks). I have tried to wrap my `Gridview` with `ScrollViewer` but that messed up. Thanks for help! Here's my code snippet:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="10,0,0,0">
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="5,10,5,5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Romances" FontSize="18"/>           
        <GridView Name="JuvenileBooks"  Grid.Row="1"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:BookModel">
                    <local:BookshelvesDataTemplate/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the thing you are looking for

```
<GridView >
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! I added Grid.Row to my scrollviewer (which wraps around my gridview) and it worked! I also tried your suggestion (replacing GridView.ItemTemplate with GridView.ItemsPanel) but that doesn't support DataTemplate

Comment: It seems you do not need to remove the `GridView.ItemTemplate` that you can  add `GridView.ItemsPanel`.